# How to merge arrays with same value and different key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Here i like to explain my problem clearly.

```
id  company ID  Employee ID Name        Relationship    Dob     Age Gender       
1   EMPL        00001       Choodamani  Spouse      11-Aug-66   49  Female            
2   EMPL        00001       Komala      Mother      30-Oct-39   76  Female            
3   EMPL        00001       Varshini    Daughter    29-Apr-04   11  Female            
4   EMPL        00001       Vasudevan   Employee    15-Jul-62   53  Male    
5   EMPL        00002       Siddharth   Son         1-Jun-00    15  Male              
6   EMPL        00002       Poongavanam Mother      21-Oct-39   76  Female            
7   EMPL        00002       Aruna       Spouse      16-Sep-68   47  Female            
8   EMPL        00002       Abirami     Daughter    7-May-97    18  Female            
9   EMPL        00002       Murali      Employee    7-Oct-67    48  Male
```

Here you can see a table, this table i have took from my db. In this data you can see that employee_id is same for first four row but id different for each row. Here what i need to merge same employee_id in one array.

example: all 00001 employee_id in one array

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you

_form.php

```
<?php

class Claim
 {
      public function Arraycombine($keys, $values)
      {
         $result = array();
         foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
           $result[$k][] = $values[$i];
         }
         array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = (count($v) == 1)?        array_pop($v): $v;'));
         return    $result;
         } 

    }

    $data1 = ArrayHelper::map(Employee::find()->all(), 'id', 'employee_id');
    $data2 = ArrayHelper::map(Employee::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');

    $claim = new Claim();

    $claimers = $claim->Arraycombine( $data1, $data2 );

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($claimers);exit(); echo "</pre>";

?>
```

ouput:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
  $new_sort = array();
  foreach ($db_array as $db_row){
    $key_row = $db_row["Employee_ID"];
    unset($db_row["Employee_ID"]);
    $new_sort[$key_row][] = $db_row;
  }
?>
```

on output you will have nested array, where $new_sort[some_employee_id] = your data

p.s if you want to create new array where name of array must be $employee_id, for example: $0001, it's impossible, because variables name must begin with a letter

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming your data is available in an associative array ($_data):
$employees = array();
foreach($_data as $employee) {
    $id = $employee['Employee ID'];
    if(isset($employees[$id])) {
        $employees[$id][] = $employee;
    } else {
        $employees[$id] = array($employee);
    }
}

// The results are now grouped, so:
$employees['00001'] = array(
    array(
        'Name' => 'Choodamani',
        // ...
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'Komala',
        // ...
    )
);
```